# Find the normalisation constant of this gamma function

Tags: r, self-study, bayesian, normalization, gamma-distribution

I have a gamma priors defined as

$$c_j \sim Ga(a_j,b_j)$$

where $b_j$ is the rate.

The component likelihoods are defined to be

$$L_j(c_j;x) = c_j^{r_j} exp\bigg\{-c_j \int_0^T g_j(x(t)) \, dt\bigg\}$$

I don't think the values of $r_j$, $g_j$ should matter

So using Bayes' theorem I can find that

$$\pi_j(c_j|x) \propto \pi(c_j)L_j(c_j;x)$$

giving

$$\propto c_j^{a_j-1} exp\{-b_jc_j\}c_j^{r_j} exp \bigg\{-c_j \int_0^T g_j(x(t)) \, dt\bigg\}$$

Now I want to find the normalisation constants of this, but I don't know how to go about this.

From this it is clear that the updated posterior is given as

$$c_j|x \sim Ga\bigg(a_j + r_j, b_j + \int_0^T g_j(x(t)) \, dt\bigg)$$

So my question is, how do I calculate the normalisation constant for this gamma distribution. The bigger picture of this is that I want to calculate the Bayes' factor between 2 similar models that follow this distribution. And I have worked out the the Bayes factor will equal the ratio of the normalisation constants.

Edit: I understand that my normalisation constant should be equal to

$$ \int_c \pi(c')L(c_j';x)\, dc'$$

but I do not know how to calculate this

Edit 2: It can be said that

$$\pi(c_j) = \frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)} c_j^{a-1} exp\big\{-bc_j\big\}$$

So surely, form earlier equations, the normalisation constant is just equal to $\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Gibbs sampling when target function is known only up to normalising constant?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331570/how-to-use-gibbs-sampling-when-target-function-is-known-only-up-to-normalising-c)

Comment: Any relevance of the index $j$ in the question? Are the different observations related? Or is there a common parameter at a higher hierarchical level?

Comment: Yeah $j$ just represents the values for the $j$th observation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convoluted structure of the observables (since $x$ is a stochastic process over $(0,T)$) does not modify the fact that the posterior on $c_i$ is a Gamma distribution, hence with inverse normalising constant
$$\Gamma(a_j+r_j)\Big/ \left[ b_j + \int_0^T g_j(x(t)) \, \text{d}t\right]^{a_j+r_j}$$
(which actually depends on how a "normalisation constant" is defined, since it is the constant that turns a given unnormalised function into a function).

Depending on the setting, the evidence associated with $L_J$ would then be$$\frac{\Gamma(a_j+r_j)}{\Gamma(a_j)}\Bigg/ \frac{\left[ b_j + \int_0^T g_j(x(t)) \, \text{d}t\right]^{a_j+r_j}}{b_j^{a_j}}$$